# Quiz about java servlet filters, unclear answer

Tags: java, servlets

I'm dealing with an unclear question about java servlet filters.

The question is:

Given a war file with the following structure

```
| – WEB-INF/classes/Myservlet.class
| – WEB-INF/lib/wf.jar
```

Where wf.jar contains a valid web-fragment.xml and the following two classes: MyFilter1.class and MyFiler2.class.
The web-fragment.xml is as follows

[image]

The following are some code snippets:

[image]

When one access “/” of the above web application, which filters will be executed?

A.
No filters will be executed.

B.
MyFilter1

C.
MyFilter2

D.
MyFilter1 and MyFilter2

I bet that the right answers would be the D (both filters), but the solutions say that the right is C (without any explanation).
Why should be executes only MyFilter2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `web-fragment.xml` has `metadata-complete=true` therefore the annotations on the classes in the jar are not evaluated and only `MyFilter2` as defined in the fragment is registered.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you did the `chain.doFilter(request,response)` in your first filter,if you chain it will go to second filter otherwise it won't.

Note that Descriptor gets more precedence than annotations if both of them are defined with the same name.this applies to both servlets and filters.

In you case when you try to access the URL with "/" it will first hit the MyFilter2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so the question doesn't speak about `chain.doFilter` then will executed only MyFilter2? Isn't?

Comment: Edited my answer,check once